# I want to change my 2d geoJSON polygon to 3D with webgl ,and how to change the verticles?

Tags: 3d, webgl, polygon

as the title said , I just want to change my 2d polygon to 3d with webgl.Just like a 2d polygon of a hotel on my map . and I want to show it in 3d by webgl . and there are some problems.
1. how to change my polygon 's coordiates to 3d .
2. how to get verticles and indexs which will be used in webgl Vshadersource. 
I just need your help . very thanks !!

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show some code samples?

Comment: emmm.. like this .let temp = [[[107.02986508564898,33.087273294576725],[107.02990045258538,33.08733097982315],[107.02990283204645,33.08734811194239].........these are coordinates . And I want to make this polygon  to 3D by webgl

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon whether you want to show your polygon on a plain map (i.e. like Google Maps) or on a sphere (i.e. like Google Earth).

In the first case you can just choose a [projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection) and convert geodesic coordinates from GeoJSON to coordinates on some plane. Here I'll you XY plane for simplicity. One of the most commonly used is [Mercator projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection#Web_Mercator). It'll given X and Y components of 3d points and Z whould be just 0. After that you'll need to tesselate the polygon into triangles (since WebGL can deal only with triangles). For that you can use of existing open source libraries, i.e. [`mapbox-earcut`](https://github.com/mapbox/earcut).

However, different maps API can render GeoJSON out-of-box, i.e. [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#geojsonsource). So you're probably better off using one of those.

Problem of showing a geo polygon on a globe is quite complex and you're certainly better off using some engine like [Cesium](https://cesiumjs.org).

Comment: ya,thank you first . now , I can show some polygon on my map ,Leaflet. And now I just want to change my 2d polygon to 3D ,and then show it on my map.And now i just want to know how to change it .

Comment: And another questions, I change my coordinates to Mercator projection. Although I have x,y,and z , but it is still a  2d polygon . I just triangluate it . it just has only one face .how can i get other faces ??

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can find some answers in Melown's github - here is the link on example which shows GPX track in 3D

https://github.com/Melown/vts-browser-js/wiki/Examples

Last example shows how to visualize GPX tracks